# Efeitos de transição em um slider

Tags: javascript, slider

Como posso aplicar efeitos de transição em um slider? Tendo como exemplo o código a seguir:

```js
function simpleSlider(type){
         var sliderActive = $("#slider .sliderActive");
          if(type == 'prev') {
           var sliderPrev   = sliderActive.prev().length ? sliderActive.prev() : $("#slider li:last");
                     sliderPrev.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
          } else {
                     var sliderNext   = sliderActive.next().length ? sliderActive.next() : $("#slider li:first");
                     sliderNext.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
                 }
                 sliderActive.removeClass('sliderActive').fadeOut();
            }
        $(function(){
            $("#slider li:first").fadeIn();
            
        });
```

```css
#slider {
    list-style:none;
    width:800px;
    height:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#slider li {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display:none;
}
#slider li.sliderActive {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
 <a href="javascript:simpleSlider('prev')"><span>prev</span></a>
 <a href="javascript:simpleSlider('next')"><span>next</span></a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slider">
    <li class="sliderActive"><div class="box_inside box_crm">
        <span class="icon_serv_crm"></span>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        <p class="principal"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</strong></p>
        <p>Maecenas sagittis, lorem non imperdiet faucibus, neque turpis porta velit, ultrices ullamcorper elit tellus in nisl. Maecenas enim felis, sollicitudin convallis tristique at, ultrices quis mauris. Pellentesque et fringilla nunc. Phasellus magna metus, placerat eget tincidunt non, dictum non nisi. </p>    
        <div class="content_btn center" style="width:100%">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Saiba mais</a>        
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="box_inside box_landing">
        <span class="icon_serv_land"></span>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        <p class="principal"><strong>t facilisis et sapien a auctor. Cras in iaculis eros, ac tincidunt mi. Aenean auctor ultricies dolor, sed dictum lectus iaculis sed. Nullam lobortis</strong></p>
        <p>t facilisis et sapien a auctor. Cras in iaculis eros, ac tincidunt mi. Aenean auctor ultricies dolor, sed dictum lectus iaculis sed. Nullam lobortis</p>    
        <div class="content_btn center" style="width:100%">
            <a href="http://localhost/" class="btn">Saiba mais</a>        
        </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu código já está usando os efeitos de `fadeIn` e `fadeOut` do `jQuery` para fazer as transições.

Basta mudar os efeitos para os que desejar que aconteçam, dê uma olhada na lista da documentação [jQuery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar plugins também para emular outros efeitos; Eu usava muito esse:

http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/

No próprio site do jquery também tem um diretório com plugins de efeito de animação:

https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/effect/